# Possible to call a function after user sets their password for the first time after using their one-time login link?

Tags: 8, users

I have a Drupal 8 site and I need to dynamically redirect the user after they set their password for the first time after using their one-time login link.

I cannot figure out any way to hook into the workflow for this condition. Is it possible?

Comment: take a look at this https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/1079018 it may help you if you want to use Rules module.

Comment: Thank you for the info. That thread is for Rules for Drupal 7. I have the Drupal 8 version installed and there is no Event Reaction for first-first time login nor for first-time password set/change.

Comment: Yeah i just pay attention to thread version, in this comment ask for the same in D8 https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2015-12-11/redirect-after-login-except-when-using-one-time-login#comment-12623894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna redirect users, the below solution won't work, because `'/user/reset/{uid}/{timestamp}/{hash}/login'` controlled by `UserController::resetPassLogin` action if you see the return of `resetPassLogin` :

> - @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
>
>   - Returns a redirect to the user edit form if the information is correct.
>   - If the information is incorrect redirects to 'user.pass' route with a
>   - message for the user.

I figure out a solution but i'm not sure if its the best way to do it:
for example if i want to redirect the user after first login to `admin/content`, i will override the `resetPassLogin` action like the following:

**myModule.routing.yml**

```
myModule.reset.login:
  path: '/user/reset/{uid}/{timestamp}/{hash}/login'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\myModule\Controller\CustomUserController::customResetPassLogin'
    _title: 'Reset password'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'FALSE'
  options:
    _maintenance_access: TRUE
    no_cache: TRUE
```

**myModule/src/Controller/CustomUserController.php**

```
namespace Drupal\myModule\Controller;

use Drupal\user\Controller\UserController;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Crypt;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class CustomUserController extends UserController {

  public function customResetPassLogin($uid, $timestamp, $hash) {
    // The current user is not logged in, so check the parameters.
    $current = REQUEST_TIME;
    /** @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user */
    $user = $this->userStorage->load($uid);

    // Verify that the user exists and is active.
    if ($user === NULL || !$user->isActive()) {
      // Blocked or invalid user ID, so deny access. The parameters will be in
      // the watchdog's URL for the administrator to check.
      throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }

    // Time out, in seconds, until login URL expires.
    $timeout = $this->config('user.settings')->get('password_reset_timeout');
    // No time out for first time login.
    if ($user->getLastLoginTime() && $current - $timestamp > $timeout) {
      $this->messenger()
        ->addError($this->t('You have tried to use a one-time login link that has expired. Please request a new one using the form below.'));
      return $this->redirect('user.pass');
    }
    elseif ($user->isAuthenticated() && ($timestamp >= $user->getLastLoginTime()) && ($timestamp <= $current) && Crypt::hashEquals($hash, user_pass_rehash($user, $timestamp))) {
      user_login_finalize($user);
      $this->logger->notice('User %name used one-time login link at time %timestamp.', [
        '%name'      => $user->getDisplayName(),
        '%timestamp' => $timestamp,
      ]);
      $this->messenger()
        ->addStatus($this->t('You have just used your one-time login link. It is no longer necessary to use this link to log in. Please change your password.'));
      // Let the user's password be changed without the current password
      // check.
      $token = Crypt::randomBytesBase64(55);
      $_SESSION['pass_reset_' . $user->id()] = $token;
      /**
       * @TODO: change the route name to yours
       */
      return $this->redirect(
        'system.admin_content',
        [],
        [
          'absolute' => TRUE,
        ]
      );
    }

    $this->messenger()
      ->addError($this->t('You have tried to use a one-time login link that has either been used or is no longer valid. Please request a new one using the form below.'));
    return $this->redirect('user.pass');
  }

}
```

**NOTE** : change `system.admin_content` by your route name.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using hook_user_login() in a custom module or theme.

```
function my_module_user_login($account) {

  // Get the end part of the URL.
  $request_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();

  // Check if the URL is a reset / one time login link.
  if (strpos($request_uri, 'user/reset') !== false) {
    _my_module_custom_function();
  }
}

function _my_module_custom_function() {
  // Do stuff.
}
```